# Java 8 Time - Convert Javascript's Date().getTimezoneOffset to ZoneOffset

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

In my web application, a user is allowed to select a time like "8:15pm" and a day like "Wednesday".  When this is sent to the server, I'm sending the String "8:15pm", "Wednesday" and the time zone information by using the Javascript method

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

This returns the offset in minutes from UTC. How can I convert something like 360 (6 hours) into a ZoneOffset so I can calculate the proper OffsetDateTime?  Is there a utility method that converts hours and a base ZoneOffset into a new ZoneOffset?

Comment: You mean like [`ZoneOffset.ofHours()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#ofHours-int-)?

Comment: What about `ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(360*60)`?

Comment: Yes, @SeanBright, that's what I was looking for.  Don't know how I missed it. You want to write it up as an answer.

Comment: @Michael It's a Javascript method as well.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

Just some food for thought, you could send the current time in millis or nano to the server which would be 64 bits or 8 bytes opposed to sending a variable length String, accompanied by the zone offet hours using another byte, or a few bits if you really want.

Also, as another user mentioned, you can create a ZoneOffset using ZoneOffset#ofHours and other helpful factory methods.

```java
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(6);
```

Example of how to convert to ZonedDateTime

```java
int offsetHours = 6; // receive from client

long millis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // received from client

ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(offsetHours);

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis), offset);
```

Comment: Worth noting, [not all timezones are whole numbers of hours](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html)

Comment: @Michael correct, some are on the half-hour.  I ended up using 
  ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(timezoneOffset * 60); as my solution (where timzoneOffset is the number of minutes from the Javascript call)

Comment: Very nice catch! Good job.

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.Date class method

> getTimezoneOffset()

and javascript Date class method

> getTimezoneOffset()

produces same output, it gives the offset value in minutes to reach GMT/UTC time from given time.

For example for

> IST(UTC +5:30)

we get (5*60)+30 = 330 minutes from UTC/GMT, the offset value is given as -330

```
int timeZoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); // for IST(UTC +5:30), we get -330

ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(-1*timeZoneOffset*60) // provides correct the ZoneOffset +05:30
```